# Is there any other way to get a cassandra hostid other than using nodetool status?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, uniqueidentifier, cassandra-3.0, nodetool

I can list complete cluster information using `nodetool status` which outputs something like this.

```
Datacenter: bi
==============
Status=Up/Down|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address       Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               
Rack
UN  10.132.2.93   19.88 GiB  32           ?       g94eee1f-1ge1-45c3-8cfgb-643719456c4fd  us-east-1a
UN  10.221.1.140  11.64 GiB  32           ?       b38f2fb2-fcf2-4567-b0cc-1548f63f0f24  us-east-1c
```

Is there a simpler way to grab the `Host ID` from the current node (the one the terminal is ssh'ed into) without having to parse it from the `status` output?

I'm using datastax enterprise... in case that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every node saves information about itself in the system.local table. You could use cqlsh to get this information.

```
cqlsh 10.132.2.93 -e 'SELECT host_id FROM system.local;'
cqlsh 10.221.1.140 -e 'SELECT host_id FROM system.local;'
```

It also saves the same type of information in system.peers table but this is only for all other nodes but itself. That's why I think it's easier to do one query for each node.

Comment: amazing.. thank you. I feel kinda stupid for not intuitively checking that table.